# how can access document in alfresco repository?

Tags: javascript, alfresco

i want to known ,how many document are in alfresco ?

What i need to do in the first?

i try to find api in Rest to access document in alfresco  but not work. i have no idea .help me please

thank in advance

Comment: Depends how you define "document"? nodes? nodes of type cm:content? nodes of type cm:content or child types? nodes in sites? etc. What are your business rules for defining this?

Comment: if i want to count all documents.what i must use types?

Comment: But what do you mean by "All Documents"? All documents where? And what do you consider to be a document? (See my other comment for some of the possible options of what you might mean)

Comment: i mean all documents in repository.

Comment: I repeat my question (and then I'll probably give up). What do you mean by "all documents"? Seriously? Alfresco supports all sorts of things, and your idea of what a document is could be very different to that of other people... If you define what you mean, we can probably help you! As it stands, all we can say is "your repository contains a non-zero number of documents, by some definition of document..." !

Comment: i'm sorry in my english.i'm comprehend is "all document" is "all file in repository" ,i'm right?.i must to count "nodes"(all file) in alfresco repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a min of 3 ways:

1. If you want to count all the documents in Alfresco use this
   [Query](http://alfrescoshare.wordpress.com/2010/01/20/count-the-total-number-of-documents-in-alfresco-using-sql/) (probably outdated)
2. Or you can write some Javascript and fire it through the Javascript-Console (addon) in Alfresco and count them. Like:

> var count = 0;
>
> recurse(companyhome, function(node) {
>       if (node.isDocument)
>         count++; });
>
> logger.log(count);

1. JMX shows the total entries, like all folders + documents. Check the [online docs](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/jmx-readonly-beans.html)